# Different kinds of Moshav Leitzim clowns

Tags: words, talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, masecheth-avodah-zarah

On [Avoda Zara 18b](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.18b.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), there's a list of multiple Moshav Leitzim examples:

> תנו רבנן ההולך לאיצטדינין ולכרקום וראה שם את הנחשים ואת החברין בוקיון
> ומוקיון ומוליון ולוליון בלורין סלגורין הרי זה מושב לצים

I'm interested in interpreting the different kinds of clowns here: בוקיון, מוקיון, מוליון, לוליון, בלורין, סלגורין. What type of clowning did each of them do?

Answer (score 7):

[Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.18b.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) doesn't translate these. But artscroll identifies

- *nehashim* with conjurers or soothsayers (see Rambam [MT Avodat Kochavim 11:4](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/912370/jewish/Avodat-Kochavim-Chapter-Eleven.htm))
- *habarin* as snake charmers
- *bukion* and *mukion* as the characters Bucco and Macchus in a Roman farce (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atellan_Farce#Stock_characters_and_Origins))
- *Salgurin* as the name of this farce (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulcinella#Characteristics))

Comment: Thanks. What about מוליון, לוליון, בלורין?

Comment: @HelterSkelter I was not able to find a translation of those, different types of clowns and jesters says Rashi (but you knew this already)

Comment: See Soncino’s note [here](https://halakhah.com/zarah/zarah_18.html#18b_5) (n. 5).